# CloudRun: Debug authentication error from curl

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, escaping, google-cloud-run

I am spinning up a container (pod/Job) from a GKE.

I have set up the appropriate Service Account on the cluster's VMs.

Therefore, when I **manually** perform a `curl` to a specific CloudRun service endpoint, I can perform the request (and get authorized and have `200` in my response)

However, when I try to automate this by setting an image to run in a `Job` as follows, I get `401`

```
      - name:  pre-upgrade-job
        image: "google/cloud-sdk"
        args:
          - curl
          - -s
          - -X
          - GET
          - -H
          - "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
          - https://my-cloud-run-endpoint
```

Here are the logs on `Stackdriver`

```
{
 httpRequest: {
  latency: "0s"   
  protocol: "HTTP/1.1"   
  remoteIp: "gdt3:r787:ff3:13:99:1234:avb:1f6b"   
  requestMethod: "GET"   
  requestSize: "313"   
  requestUrl: "https://my-cloud-run-endpoint"   
  serverIp: "212.45.313.83"   
  status: 401   
  userAgent: "curl/7.59.0"   
 }
 insertId: "29jdnc39dhfbfb"  
 logName: "projects/my-gcp-project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-09-26T16:27:30.681513204Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name: "my-cloud-run-service"    
   location: "us-east1"    
   project_id: "my-gcp-project"    
   revision_name: "my-cloudrun-service-d5dbd806-62e8-4b9c-8ab7-7d6f77fb73fb"    
   service_name: "my-cloud-run-service"    
  }
  type: "cloud_run_revision"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 textPayload: "The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating"  
 timestamp: "2019-09-26T16:27:30.673565Z"  
}
```

My question is how can I see if an "Authentication" header does reach the endpoint (the logs do not enlighten me much) and if it does, whether it is appropriately rendered upon image command/args invocation.

Comment: Error 401 means "Request had invalid credentials". `gcloud` is a script. This means that the job needs to launch a shell and run a python program. This is probably failing. On the receiving service, turn off IAP and manually log the HTTP headers. Your received HTTP authorization header probably looks like this `Authorization: bearer `. Note that the token is probably missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your job you use this container `google/cloud-sdk` which is a from scratch installation of `gcloud` tooling. It's generic, without any customization.

When you call this `$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)` you ask for the identity token of the service account configured in the `gcloud` tool.

If we put together this 2 paragraphs, you want to generate an identity token from a generic/blank installation of `gcloud` tool. By the way, you don't have defined service account in your `gcloud` and your token is empty (like @johnhanley said).

For solving this issue, add an environment variable like this

```
env: 
  - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL=<path to your credential.json>
```

I don't know where is your current `credential.json` of your running environment. Try to perform an `echo` of this env var to find it and forward it correctly to your `gcloud` job.

If you are on compute engine or similar system compliant with metadata server, you can get a correct token with this command:

```
curl  -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=<URL of your service>"
```

**UPDATE**

Try to run your command outside of the `gcloud` container. Here the update of your job

```
 - name:  pre-upgrade-job
        image: "google/cloud-sdk"
        entrypoint: "bash"
        args:
          - -c
          - "curl -s -X GET -H \"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)\" https://my-cloud-run-endpoint"
```

Not sure that works. Let me know

Comment: pls see the comment I posted to user Steren

Answer (score 1):

In your Job, `gcloud auth print-identity-token` likely does not return any tocken.
The reason is that locally, gcloud uses your identity to mint a token, but in a Job, you are not logged into gcloud.

Comment: I do not have to be logged into an account given that the `pod` has a GCP ServiceAccount (the one of the underlying VM) attached to it. I have tried the above command and it works when performed manually. `gcloud auth print-identity-token` **does** return a token when the VM has a SA attached.